# n+=1 returns 0 python function cannot change variable

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables

```
n=0
def add(n):
   print n
   n+=1
   print n
   return n
```

whatever I do to "n" it is returned as 0. If I start n=0 and use add(n) I get n=0 back again. The "print n" after "n+=1" is "n=1". "return n" somehow transforms "n" back to "0" or does it have to do with a global "n=0" that I cannot change no matter what? I don't understand what is going on. How do I create a variable that can be changed in functions (from one function to another...).

Comment: `add(0)` *will* return `1`, but if you don't print that return value or don't assign it anywhere, the global `n` remains unaffected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is a *local* variable in `add()`, and as such it is not the same variable as the *global* `n`. The two are (quite deliberately) not connected.

If you want to change the global, you have two options:

1. reassign the return value from `add()` back to the global `n`:

   ```
   n = add(n)
   ```
2. alter the global directly by marking the name `n` in `add` as a global. Your `add()` function doesn't need to use an argument in that case:

   ```
   def add():
       global n
       n += 1
   ```